# how can I set null environment variable as value for .net core appsetting?

Tags: .net-core, environment-variables, appsettings

How can I set null value from environment variable.

Explanation: I am using a library which read configuration from environment variables. library has default value in case I don't override it from environment variable. My need is to set null as value for the property.

I have tried specifying null in environment variable but it appears as string "null".

Comment: which environment variable ?

Comment: why would you set something that has default value?

Comment: @qamar Because of possible nullability